# Indicate on the $x$-$y$ plane the set of all points $(x,y)$ for which $[x]^2 + [y]^2 = 4$

Tags: calculus, number-theory

Indicate on the $x$-$y$ plane the set of all points $(x,y)$ for which $$[x]^2 + [y]^2 = 4$$
Where $[x]$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $[x]$ and $[y]$ are integers and we have
$$[y]^2={4-[x]^2}$$
thus there is only two possibilities for $[x]$, namely
$$[x]=0\quad\text{or}\quad [x]=\pm2$$
therefore we have
$$[x]=0 \text{ and }[y]=\pm2 $$
or $$[x]=\pm2 \text{ and }[y]=0 $$
that is 
$$x\in[0,1) \text{ and }y\in[2,3)\cup[-2,-1)$$
or
$$x\in[2,3)\cup[-2,-1) \text{ and }y\in[0,1)$$

Answer (score 3):

[image: visualization of the answer]

This is just a visualization of @Qurultay's answer

Comment: Very nice. Thank you.